# How can I find the missing values from a data.frame column by group and append all values (both missing and found) into a result data.frame in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, merge, missing-data, fill

How can I create desired_data from sample_data (without a loop) in R?

Sample data:

```
sample_data1 <- data.frame(group=c("L1","L1","L1","L1","L1","L1"),class=c("A","A","B","B","C","C"),data=c(1,1,1,1,1,1),stringsAsFactors = F)
sample_data2 <- data.frame(group=c("L2","L2","L2","L2","L2","L2"),class=c("A","A",NA,NA,"D","D"),data=c(1,1,1,1,1,1),stringsAsFactors = F)
sample_data3 <- data.frame(group=c("L3","L3","L3","L3","L3","L3"),class=c(NA,NA,NA,NA,"C","C"),data=c(1,1,1,1,1,1),stringsAsFactors = F)
sample_data4 <- data.frame(group=c("L4","L4","L4","L4","L4","L4"),class=c(NA,NA,"B","B","C","C"),data=c(1,1,1,1,1,1),stringsAsFactors = F)
sample_data5 <- data.frame(group=c("L5","L5","L5","L5","L5","L5"),class=c(NA,NA,"E","E",NA,NA),data=c(1,1,1,1,1,1),stringsAsFactors = F)
sample_data <- rbind(sample_data1,sample_data2,sample_data3, sample_data4,sample_data5)
```

Creating desired_data sample:

```
desired_data1 <- data.frame(group=c("L1","L1","L1","L1","L1","L1","L1","L1","L1","L1"),class=c("A","A","B","B","C","C","D","D","E","E"),data=c(1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0),stringsAsFactors = F)
desired_data2 <- data.frame(group=c("L2","L2","L2","L2","L2","L2","L2","L2","L2","L2"),class=c("A","A","B","B","C","C","D","D","E","E"),data=c(1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0),stringsAsFactors = F)
desired_data3 <- data.frame(group=c("L3","L3","L3","L3","L3","L3","L3","L3","L3","L3"),class=c("A","A","B","B","C","C","D","D","E","E"),data=c(0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0),stringsAsFactors = F)
desired_data4 <- data.frame(group=c("L4","L4","L4","L4","L4","L4","L4","L4","L4","L4"),class=c("A","A","B","B","C","C","D","D","E","E"),data=c(0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0),stringsAsFactors = F)
desired_data5 <- data.frame(group=c("L5","L5","L5","L5","L5","L5","L5","L5","L5","L5"),class=c("A","A","B","B","C","C","D","D","E","E"),data=c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1),stringsAsFactors = F)
desired_data <- rbind(desired_data1,desired_data2,desired_data3,desired_data4,desired_data5)
```

Answer (score 0):

Every row in the sample data and the desired data is repeated twice - was that intentional?

```
library(tidyverse)

tibble(group = rep(paste0("L", 1:5), each = 5),
         class = rep(c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E"),5)) %>%
         left_join(distinct(sample_data)) %>%
         replace_na(list(data = 0)) %>%
         {bind_rows(.,.)} # if the answer is yes, then keep this line on. If not, remove it (along with the pipe on the previous line)
```